# Heroku application issues: connection timeout when using heroku redis plan above mini

Tags: python, flask, heroku, redis, celery

I am experiencing a timeout issue when attempting to connect to my Redis server on Heroku. I have configured my application to use TLS for the connection, as shown in the following Python code:

````
python
Copy code
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import redis

url = urlparse(os.environ.get("REDIS_URL"))
r = redis.Redis(host=url.hostname, port=url.port, password=(redacted)), ssl=True, ssl_cert_reqs=None)```

When I run this code on Heroku, I encounter a timeout error. However, when I test the same code locally by setting the REDIS_URL environment variable to my Redis server's URL, the connection is successful and I can perform basic Redis operations without any issues.

Here is how I was handling the TLS connection to the redis server on my code:

```os.environ["REDIS_URL"] = "redisURL"

def backend_url_with_tls(redis_url):
url = urlparse(redis_url)
query = "ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE"
return urlunparse((url.scheme, url.netloc, url.path, url.params, query, url.fragment))

redis_url = os.environ.get("REDIS_URL")
backend_url = backend_url_with_tls(redis_url)

app = Celery('chatbot_tasks', broker=redis_url, backend=backend_url)```

I had to downgrade to the mini plan because I can't find a solution to this issue.
````